# Did I accidentally brew nettle liqueur?

Tags: wine

I was brewing nettle wine in a fairly amateurish way. The ingredients were:

- Stinging nettle leafs/leaves
- Lotsa water
- Lotsa sugar
- Some lemon juice
- Dry baker's yeast intended for baking pastries

I fermented the concoction for one week, then pasteurized it by nearly boiling.
The end result is thicker than expected, and had the texture and taste of egg liqueur. If I didn't make it myself, I could be fooled into thinking that it is egg liqueur.
Did I accidentally brew nettle liqueur instead of nettle wine?

Answer (score 1):

Since you "nearly boiled" post fermentation most your alcohol is probably gone as it vaporizes around 180°F.

Sounds like you now have **Nettle Syrup**.

Comment: To be fair, it still tastes very alcoholic and gave me a buzz, and smells like wine. Maybe I didn't "nearly boil" it then? It only bubbled somewhat. It probably didn't even come close to 100°, let alone 180° (Celsius).

Comment: Ah, the fun of people just assuming everybody uses Fahrenheit when everybody actually uses Celsius... ;-P

Comment: Edited to reflect 180°F. If it simmered or bubbled or did anything reduce volume and thicken. Then most of the alcohol will be gone, maybe not all but far from being a liqueur

Comment: I would concur. The product is most likely some form of alcoholic "nettle syrup". A OG/FG readings would be needed to indicate how alcoholic. Allowing for evaporation losses...

Answer (score 0):

The pasteurizing temperature (for milk at least) and the boiling point of alcohol lay fairly close to each other, but the boiling point of alcohol just a bit higher. You could be lucky and hit it right in between, otherwise it isn't pasteurized properly or you boiled off some percentage of the alcohol content. Keep in mind bakers yeast is intended to produce a lot CO2 to make bread fluffy, and not so much alcohol.

Did you do any measurements to get a general idea of the alcohol content? Measurements are key in homebrewing. Is it supposed to be 4% or more close 40% (not possible, but hey, shoot for the stars right)?

Comment: I did not measure it, but it definitely feels more alcoholic then beer. I think it may be 10% or even 20%.

Comment: The production of CO2 and alcohol are in a fixed ratio. Bakers yeast and champagne yeast produce the same ratio of alcohol/CO2. The only significant difference in this respect is in the attenuation level of each yeast. Plus I doubt that "bakers yeast" would ferment to anything near 20% ABV